# How to solve $x \log^2x - c=0$?

Tags: calculus

I'm optimizing parameters to an algorithm  to minimize its run time. Substituting some variables to clean up the presentation, I basically need to solve
$x \log^2x -  c=0$, but I forget how to solve an equation of this form.  How can I do this?

Comment: There isn't a solution that can be written in terms of elementary functions.  This is because you have an $x$ both inside and out of a transcendental function.

Comment: You can solve numerically using, e.g., Newton's Method, q.v.

Comment: Can I approximate it as a function of c? Maybe as a series orsomething?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use [Lambert's $W$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) to solve this. But keep in mind that for $0<c\leq 4 e^{-2}$ the solution is not unique:

[image]

For completeness, the possible solutions are:
$$
\begin{align}
&x=\exp\left[2W_0\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\right)\right],\ \exp\left[2W_{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\right)\right] & 0<c\leq 4 e^{-2}\\
&x=\exp\left[2W_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\right)\right] & 4 e^{-2}<c\\
\end{align}
$$
Where $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$ are the two branches of the $W$ function, as described in the wikipedia link. I don't know what software you use, but there's no need to resort to numerical root finding - the $W$-function is implemented in [mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html), [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/lambertw.html), and [C++](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/).

---

***EDIT***

Since you asked about the assymptotics, I'll add that for large $c$ we have 
$$x(c)=\exp\left[2W_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\right)\right]=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{c}{\log^2 c}\right)\ .$$
Actually the following limit holds exatcly:
$$
\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac{x(c)}{c/\log^2 c}=\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac{\exp\left[2W_0\left(\frac{\sqrt{c}}{2}\right)\right]}{c/\log^2 c}=1
$$
I got this result by playing with mathematica, and I didn't bother proving it.

Note, though, that it takes a *very large* $c$ to achieve this limit. I give here the plot of this ratio as a function of $c$:

[image]

Comment: I'm doing asymptomatic analysis. c can be assumed very large. After skimming the Wikipedia article, it's still not clear how x will be bounded asymptotically.

Comment: What do you mean? I gave an explicit expression for $x$ as a funcion of $c$.

Comment: I mean I don't have intuition for how $W(z)$ grows compared to $z$.
Specifically, $W(z) = O(f(z))$ for what elementary function $f$? Is there one?

Comment: +1 though, since now I at least know what $W_0$ is referring to.

Comment: @joe see my updated answer.

Comment: Note that the $x$ appearing in the denominator of the 2nd/final graph's vertical axis label should be $c$.  I don't know how much work it would be to fix the graphic.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can do this analytically, but you could do it pretty quickly numerically and that seems like it should be good enough. Just write $x \log^2 x - c = 0$ as 
$$ x = \exp\left( (c/x)^{1/2} \right ) $$
and then numerically find a fixed point. This will work if c is positive and if your initial guess is positive, otherwise you might run into problems.

A quick calculation show the following values for 20 iterations with a starting value of $x=10$ and $c=1$:

```
{10, 1.37194, 2.34844, 1.92042, 2.05774, 2.00795, 2.02527, 2.01916,
2.02131, 2.02055, 2.02082, 2.02072, 2.02076, 2.02074, 2.02075,
2.02075, 2.02075, 2.02075, 2.02075, 2.02075, 2.02075}.
```

However, this method can be quite unstable for certain choices of c.

Like you mentioned, you could probably try to approximate with a Taylor expansion. Newton's method uses a second order taylor series to find roots. But, I suppose you'd like some way to find the appropriate x more directly or more automatically. To approximate with a Taylor series you would have to choose a point to expand around. If you chose to expand around x=b to the second order, then you would get the approximation
$$ x \log ^2(x)-c \approx \left(b \log ^2(b)-c\right)+(x-b) \left(\log ^2(b)+2 \log (b)\right)+\frac{(x-b)^2
   (\log (b)+1)}{b}+O\left((x-b)^3\right)$$.
You could then solve for x, given c:
$$x = \frac{2 b-b \log ^2(b) \pm\sqrt{b} \sqrt{4 c \log (b)+b \log ^4(b)+4 c}}{2 (\log
   (b)+1)}$$

A Taylor expansion of a higher degree would make this solving step pretty complicated and you'd have to deal with more roots.

I feel like the problem here, though, is that you wouldn't know where to expand around. And to expand around one particular point and use that for all values of c would be problematic because the approximation can get pretty bad the farther you get from the expansion point. I'm not really sure what to do. Good luck, though!

Comment: Convergence of the fixed point iteration $x := f(x)$ is usually easy to work out from the first derivative of $f$.  In particular if we can limit ourselves to an interval where $|f'(x)| \lt 1$, then the fixed point iteration converges by "contraction".